# Necessity of the @Parent annotation

Tags: entity, objectify

I am relooking at the objectify documentation and wondering what the benefit or necessity of the @Parent annotation is. It appears as keys or refs would do the trick. Any way you can share your experience on what the necessity or benefit is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Parent gives you two benefits:

- All entities with a common ancestor count as a single entity group in transactions.
- You can perform strongly-consistent ancestor queries.

Some useful reading here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have few open questions on this topic. Any guidance would be appreciated. Q1) what is best to work with parent/child relationships: ref or key? Q2) From what I am reading, these are not serialized by objectify so either you do not serialize them (ApiResourceProperty) or you create a transformer class. Do you point me to examples on how to create such a class? I did not find many examples. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand Q2, but for Q1 the answer is "it doesn't matter". They are stored identically (as native Key) in the datastore so you can change your code at will. Use that is most convenient, and if you find the other approach is more convenient, switch.